# Get Mic data callbacks for 20 Miliseconds VoIP App

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, real-time, avaudiosession

I am developing VOIP calling app so now I am in the stage where I need to transfer the voice data to the server. For that I want to get Real time audio voice data from mic with 20 mili Seconds callbacks.

I did searched many links but I am unable find solution as 
i am new to audio frameworks.

Details

We have our own stack like WebRTC which gives RTP sends data from remote for every 20 mili second and asks data from Mic for 20 mili second , What I am trying to achieve is to get 20 mili second data from mic and pass it the same to the stack. So need to know how to do so. Audio format is pcmFormatInt16 and sample rate is 8000 Hz with 20 mili seconds data.

I have searched for

**AVAudioEngine,
AUAudioUnit,
AVCaptureSession Etc.**

- 1.I am Using AVAudioSession and AUAudioUnit but setPreferredIOBufferDuration of audioSession is not setting with exact value what i have set. In result of that i am not getting the exact data size. Can anybody help me on setPreferredIOBufferDuration.
- 2.One more issue is auAudioUnit.outputProvider () is giving inputData in UnsafeMutableAudioBufferListPointer. inputData list has two element and I want only one sample. Can anybody help me on that to change it into data format which can be played in AVAudioPlayer.

I have followed before link
https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/ba815fc23b5d642705f2b1dedfaf0107

```
let hwSRate = audioSession.sampleRate

try audioSession.setActive(true)

 print("native Hardware rate : \(hwSRate)")

try audioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(preferredIOBufferDuration)

try audioSession.setPreferredSampleRate(8000) // at 8000.0 Hz

print("Changed native Hardware rate : \(audioSession.sampleRate) buffer duration \(audioSession.ioBufferDuration)")


try auAudioUnit = AUAudioUnit(componentDescription: self.audioComponentDescription)



auAudioUnit.outputProvider = { // AURenderPullInputBlock

                (actionFlags, timestamp, frameCount, inputBusNumber, inputData) -> AUAudioUnitStatus in



                    if let block = self.renderBlock {       // AURenderBlock?
                let err : OSStatus = block(actionFlags,
                                           timestamp,
                                           frameCount,
                                           1,
                                           inputData,
                                           .none)
                if err == noErr {
                    // save samples from current input buffer to circular buffer
                    print("inputData = \(inputData) and frameCount: \(frameCount)")
                    self.recordMicrophoneInputSamples(
                        inputDataList:  inputData,
                        frameCount: UInt32(frameCount) )
                }
            }
            let err2 : AUAudioUnitStatus = noErr
            return err2
```

}

Log:-

Changed native Hardware rate : 8000.0 buffer duration 0.01600000075995922

Answer (score 1):

try to get 40 ms data from the Audio interface and then split it up into 20ms data.

also check if you are able to set the sampling frequency (8 Khz) of the audio interface.

Comment: You mean to say same implementation with 40ms as ioBufferDuration. Another problem is when validate input data into render blocks it was giving -50 OSStatus.if let block = self.renderBlock {       // AURenderBlock? let err : OSStatus = block(actionFlags, timestamp,frameCount,1,inputData,.none) if err == noErr {}}

Comment: i hope you have read and filled the parameter correctly  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/aurenderblock

Comment: Sample application : https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/ba815fc23b5d642705f2b1dedfaf0107

Comment: I have used this link https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/ba815fc23b5d642705f2b1dedfaf0107  RecordAudio_v2 version2 when i was giving audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.record) then I was not getting callback inside OutputProvider If i change it to playAndRecord then it was giving me -50 OSStatus error inside renderBlock.

Comment: Here is one more link for similar issue. you can check the interface used https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29942310/aurendercallbackstruct-in-swift

Comment: I have implemented the mic data scenario and its working fine. Now we need to implement reverse of it. Feeding data to speaker sample size of 160 or 320 PCM data. How can we achieve it in swift. How i can achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Render block will give you call backs according to the accepted set up by hardware for AUAudioUnit and AudioSession. We have to manage buffer if we want different size of input from mic. Output to the speaker should be same size as it expects like 128, 256 ,512 bytes etc.

```
   try audioSession.setPreferredSampleRate(sampleRateProvided) // at 48000.0
   try audioSession.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(preferredIOBufferDuration)
```

**These values can be different from our preferred size. That is why we have to use buffer logic get out preferred size of input.**

Link: https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/ba815fc23b5d642705f2b1dedfaf0107

```
renderBlock = auAudioUnit.renderBlock
    if (   enableRecording
        && micPermissionGranted
        && audioSetupComplete
        && audioSessionActive
        && isRecording == false ) {

        auAudioUnit.inputHandler = { (actionFlags, timestamp, frameCount, inputBusNumber) in
            if let block = self.renderBlock {       // AURenderBlock?
                var bufferList = AudioBufferList(
                    mNumberBuffers: 1,
                    mBuffers: AudioBuffer(
                        mNumberChannels: audioFormat!.channelCount,
                        mDataByteSize: 0,
                        mData: nil))

                let err : OSStatus = block(actionFlags,
                                           timestamp,
                                           frameCount,
                                           inputBusNumber,
                                           &bufferList,
                                           .none)
                if err == noErr {
                    // save samples from current input buffer to circular buffer
                    print("inputData = \(bufferList.mBuffers.mDataByteSize) and frameCount: \(frameCount) and count: \(count)")
                    count += 1
                    if !self.isMuteState {
                        self.recordMicrophoneInputSamples(
                            inputDataList:  &bufferList,
                            frameCount: UInt32(frameCount) )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        auAudioUnit.isInputEnabled  = true
        auAudioUnit.outputProvider = { (    //  AURenderPullInputBlock?
            actionFlags,
            timestamp,
            frameCount,
            inputBusNumber,
            inputDataList ) -> AUAudioUnitStatus in
            if let block = self.renderBlock {
                if let  dataReceived = self.getInputDataForConsumption() {
                    let mutabledata = NSMutableData(data: dataReceived)

                    var bufferListSpeaker = AudioBufferList(
                        mNumberBuffers: 1,
                        mBuffers: AudioBuffer(
                            mNumberChannels: 1,
                            mDataByteSize: 0,
                            mData: nil))
                    let err : OSStatus = block(actionFlags,
                                               timestamp,
                                               frameCount,
                                               1,
                                               &bufferListSpeaker,
                                               .none)
                    if err == noErr {
                        bufferListSpeaker.mBuffers.mDataByteSize = UInt32(mutabledata.length)
                        bufferListSpeaker.mBuffers.mData = mutabledata.mutableBytes
                        inputDataList[0] = bufferListSpeaker
                        print("Output Provider mDataByteSize: \(inputDataList[0].mBuffers.mDataByteSize) output FrameCount: \(frameCount)")
                        return err
                    } else {
                        print("Output Provider \(err)")
                        return err
                    }
                }
            }
            return 0
        }
        auAudioUnit.isOutputEnabled  = true

        do {
            circInIdx   =   0                       // initialize circular buffer pointers
            circOutIdx  =   0
            circoutSpkIdx = 0
            circInSpkIdx = 0
            try auAudioUnit.allocateRenderResources()
            try auAudioUnit.startHardware()         // equivalent to AudioOutputUnitStart ???
            isRecording = true

        } catch let e {
            print(e)
        }
```